# Extract a table from plain text file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to Powershell and need help in extracting table data that is there in a plain text file.

The plain text file data is in the below format.(Tab Separated)

Header1 Header2 Header3

Val1    Val2    Val3

Now, I want to extract this data and populate the variables like below.

```
 $Header1 = "Val1"
 $Header2 = "Val2"
 $Header3 = "Val3"
```

Please help me with the right approach.

Comment: Have you considered using [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7) ?  You may explain the actual task - not the approach you think you need to accomplish this task.  ;-)

Comment: Hi Olaf, the source file is not a csv in fact.
The actual task for me is just to populate the header variables like I've shown in the question.

Comment: Yes, it really is a csv file, only it uses tab instead of comma as the delimiter.  Take a look at the delimiter parameter in Import-csv.

Comment: Thank you @WalterMitty, I wasn't aware of that, yeah you and Olaf were right. 
I just started learning PS and had a different idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you need to `import-csv` and use the `-delimeter` parameter and specify a tab as shown below

```
PS C:\Temp> $g = import-csv textfilewithtabs.txt -Delimiter "`t"

PS C:\Temp> $g

header1 header2 header3
------- ------- -------
value1  value2  value3 


PS C:\Temp> $g | select header2

header2
-------
value2 

PS C:\Temp> $g.header1
value1

PS C:\Temp> $g.header2
value2
```

Comment: Hi Itchydon, this worked like charm! Thank you very much! :)